# Why won't my SaveFileDialog appear when using TPL in a full-trust XBAP?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, xbap

I have an app which reads a data file and converts it to a CSV file. Ideally, I'd like the read to be processing in the background while the user selects a location to save the .csv file to, however the `SaveFileDialog` doesn't show up when `.ShowDialog()` is called from another thread

```
void ReadFile(string inputFile)
{
    var readFileTask = Task.Factory.StartNew<string>(() => ReadFile(inputFile));
    var getSaveFileTask = Task.Factory.StartNew<string>(() => GetSaveFile());

    // Wait until both tasks are finished
    Task.WaitAll(new Task[] { readFileTask , getSaveFileTask });

    var data = readFileTask.Result;
    var saveLocation = getSaveFileTask.Result;

    // Save data as CSV file
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => WriteCsvFile(saveLocation));
}

private string GetSaveFile()
{
    SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
    sfd.Filter = "Csv Files|*.csv";
    sfd.Title = "Select location to save file to";

    // This get hit but dialog never appears when called from another thread
    sfd.ShowDialog(); 
    return sfd.FileName;
}
```

It works fine in a regular WPF application, so I am assuming it has something to do with this being an XBAP. The XBAP is set to run as full-trust

Comment: I don't know about XBAP, but in Silverlight you cannot show a SaveFileDialog unless it is from a "User Initiated Action".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you have to call SaveFileDialog.ShowDialog from the UI thread.
Try:

`var getSaveFileTask = Task.Factory.StartNew<string>(() => GetSaveFile(), CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());`